# Replace variable with # and pass function body as an argument to a function

Tags: pure-function, hold, inverse

I have a very simple problem, which I would like to make a bit general, but none of my naive approaches have worked yet.

This is what I want to do step by step:

Define a parameter:

```
Protect[par1]
par1
```

Define some rules that assign later on par1 to a number:

```
rule = {par1->0.5}

rulemod= {Log[10 par1] -> Log[10*0.5]}
```

Define a symbolic function that transforms my parameter:

```
fOfPar = Log[10 par1]
```

At the end of the day I want to find the inverse function of fOfPar:

```
inverseFunc = 
  InverseFunction[
     ConditionalExpression[Log[10  #], (Element[#1, Reals] && #1 > 0)] &]
```

> ConditionalExpression[E^#1/10,#1[Element]Reals]&

```
inverseFunc[1.60944]
```

> 0.500001

Until here, everything fine. But I would like to construct a function, that given a symbolic function of `par1`, "strips" `par1` from the symbolic function, replaces somehow by # and returns the inverse function.

Maybe I am completely wrong in my use of Block and Attributes, but this is what I've tried sofar:

```
ClearAll[passFuncToInverse]
SetAttributes[passFuncToInverse, HoldFirst];
passFuncToInverse[x_]:=Block[{xy, xx,para=par1},
     xx = (x)/.{para->#};
      InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[ReleaseHold[xx],  (Element[#1,Reals]&& #1>0)]& ]
```

]

```
 passFuncToInverse[fOfPar]
```

> InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[ReleaseHold[xx],#1\  [Element]Reals&&#1>0]&]

```
passFuncToInverse[Log[10 par1]]
```

> InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[ReleaseHold[xx],#1[Element]Reals&&#1>0]&]

I know I am doing something wrong, but I guess this should be a possible thing to do in Mathematica.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why you need the symbolic function to depend on `par1` to begin with? If you are gonne replace `par1`  by `#` anyway, why not start with `#`? Is it related to how you generate the symbolic function?

Comment: Yes, well this is part of a bigger program. The idea is that the 'user' can give through a rule, either the value par1 or the value of F[ par1]. F is a symbolic function. I need to keep the rule like that, because it is needed in many other places. For some computations later on, F[par1] is more convenient and for others,  par1 is better. This function F can change depending on the application. So in this way the user doesn't need to worry about specifying both.

Comment: For the "replace `par1` with `#`" part you can use `Function[par1,Log[10 par1]]`. But Bob Hanlon's answer might be better...

Comment: Your description "to construct a function, that given a symbolic function of par1, "strips" par1 from the symbolic function, replaces somehow by # and returns the inverse function" is a bit abstract in my view, I think you'd better add a specific example for the expected input and corresponding output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html)

```
f[par1_] = Log[10  par1];

invf = InverseFunction[f]

(*  ConditionalExpression[E^#1/10, -π < Im[#1] <= π] &  *)

invf[f[x]] // FullSimplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &

(*  x  *)

f[invf[x]] // Simplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &

(*  x  *)

invf[f[#]] & /@ {1/2, .5, 1, 1.}

(*  {1/2, 0.5, 1, 1.}  *)

f[invf[#]] & /@ {1/2, .5, 1, 1.}

(*  {1/2, 0.5, 1, 1.}  *)
```